# Preferred return type, pointer or value, when the method/function can also return an error

Tags: go

In `Go` we can choose to make something a pointer or not. We can also support multiple return types. A common signature on functions or methods is:

```
type MyType struct{}

// Value Return Type
func (m MyType) FindOne(key string)(MyType, error) {...}

// Pointer Return Type
func (m MyType) FindOne(key string)(*MyType, error) {...}
```

In reviewing the repos on Github (non-exhaustive) for signatures like the above, **it seems to be preferred to use the pointer style return type when something can also return an error. Is that the general consensus?**

Few Examples (again non-exhaustive I have definitely not seen everything there is to see):

https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/9c5426830b1b8728af14e069acfdc2a64dea768c/clientv3/kv.go#L48-L54

https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/d19aba07b47683ef19378c4a4d43959672b7cec8/cluster.go#L329

https://github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache/blob/master/memcache/memcache.go#L317

In thinking about it, and here's where my question lies, I would think the pointer style would be preferred on calls where a result might not exist:

```
service := MyType{}
result, err := service.FindOne("not-found-key")
```

In this way `result` can be `nil` and only the `err` has a value. Effectively preventing anyone from operating `result`. Whereas in the value type return, if nothing is found, we would still need to return an empty `MyType{}`. Assuming we are good *Go* citizens, we would naturally error check things always. Nothing is perfect and things slip by, so in the case where someone were to do something like this:

```
service := MyType{}
result, _ := service.FindOne("not-found-key")

// do stuff with `result` because of course it will ALWAYS succeed
// we don't need to error check (until we do)
```

The execution will continue even though we are now in a potentially unknown state. Where as is we tried to do things to that pointer return value, since it's `nil`, it would panic and we'd know about it right away.

This has additional implications as well in the design of our `MyType` service. To keep things consistent, if we introduced at `FindMany` method:

```
type MyType struct{}

func (m MyType) FindOne(key string)(*MyType, error) {...}
func (m MyType) FindMany(key string)([]*MyType, error) {...}
```

We would probably benefit from keeping the Pointer return types consistent so callers don't have to think too much as it's always the same either a Pointer or Value of `MyType`.

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?  That's the question you have to ask yourself.  Then you make a decision.  I don't know if Go works like other languages, but in most languages the reason you use a pointer or reference is because (in general) you want to keep things on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: Found a nice reference explaining at least in 2017, how Go deals with things: https://segment.com/blog/allocation-efficiency-in-high-performance-go-services/

Comment: The pointer return type also maps better to a "no result found" instead of an empty result if you choose value semantics. With your `FindMany()` receiver the zero value of a slice is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it particularly matters which you use, at least not relating to error handling.  The whole point of returning an *err* along with a result is so that you can test for an error *before* accessing the return result.  So ultimately it shouldn't matter if your return a valid , because if you are properly checking the error result first, an invalid  would never be referenced.